# How can I stream the display from the raspberry pi so that it shows on my windows ten laptop

Tags: display, remote, vnc

I have found that setting up the Raspberry Pi with a television is difficult sometimes. I would like to get it working through my laptop instead to save space when I need to.

I have looked at multiple online guides but they do not seem to work for me. I have tried using the VNC server but the guide I looked at told me to set up a Local Area Connection using an Ethernet cable from my laptop to Raspberry Pi.

I was unable to do this, so if there is any other way I can, could someone please show me?

Comment: Are you talking about remote desktop ? You can use vnc server and client or xrdp for this purpose.

Comment: I have tried using the vnc server to do this before but i cant get it working, I couldn't set up the Local Area Connection on my laptop, possibly because it is windows 10. Is there any chance you could explain how to use the remote desktop with vnc please?

Comment: How is Rpi connected on network ? Using LAN / wifi ? This link sounds like a good way to start : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/

Comment: "I have looked at multiple guides...I have tried everything...but nothing works" does not differentiate this from just asking for material you've already seen anyway.  If you have a problem doing something specific, *explain the problem*.  **In detail.**  Otherwise all anyone can say is, "Oh well, I guess you are stuck then."  It's *your* problem. [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).